# Solar shade act in CA

Tags: california, trees

If a neighbors tree that is shading a solar power system that was installed many years ago (2009 homes were built in 2004) in CA (tree might have been existing in a shorter form and the trees grow very quickly), what are the legal obligations of the neighbor to trim the tree?

Answer (score 4):

[The Act](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?lawCode=PRC&division=15.&title=&part=&chapter=12.&article=) requires that

> After the installation of a solar collector, a person owning or in
>   control of another property shall not allow a tree or shrub to be
>   placed or, if placed, to grow on that property so as to cast a shadow
>   greater than 10 percent of the collector absorption area upon that
>   solar collector surface at any one time between the hours of 10 a.m.
>   and 2 p.m., local standard time.

The subsequent paragraph pertains to notice that can be given to property owners, and ultimately the tree would be deemable to be a public nuisance and subject to removal. **However** (25984):

> This chapter does not apply to any of the following:
>
> (a) A tree or shrub planted prior to the installation of a solar
>   collector.
>
> (b) A tree planted, grown, or harvested on timberland as defined in
>   Section 4526 or on land devoted to the production of commercial
>   agricultural crops.
>
> (c) The replacement of a tree or shrub that had been growing prior to
>   the installation of a solar collector and that, subsequent to the
>   installation of the solar collector, dies, or is removed for the
>   protection of public health, safety, or the environment.
>
> (d) A tree or shrub that is subject to a city or county ordinance.

In other words, if you place a collector where an existing plant can eventually cause shade on the collector (it can be a short tree), you have no remedy. This follows the doctrine of [coming to the nuisance](https://people.ucsc.edu/~wittman/nuisance.html).